# Asked design pattern question that was put on hold as off-topic - why?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

Here the link to the question:
[ExtensionPoints design and architecture with examples](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238139/extensionpoints-design-and-architecture-with-examples)

Comment: REF: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14367/discussion-between-tatigo-and-robert-harvey

Comment: Please note the *original* version of the question that was closed can be seen as revision 1: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/238139/1

Comment: it's the same question but with more words put into it :) I used to the stackoverflow style, that the shorter the question the better

Comment: With your update, the new question is better focused. I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

The [original question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/238139/1) reads:

> Can any one suggest a good (but simple) read on the design of ExtensionPoints for Asp.net?

That question is a polling for books to read and could be closed as either 'too broad' or 'recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.'

There is no problem presented in the question. It is a request for resources which lead to (poor) link only answers that rot over time.

Comment: ok, i do need help with opinions and discussions, any suggestion where should I post my question?

Comment: You might want to look at various forums and meet ups associated with ASP.NET. I rarely touch the Microsoft stack of software and wouldn't be able to give any advice on where to look.

Comment: @tatigo ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: why those questions are allowed, very subjective and opinion based:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238413/how-to-deal-with-team-members-writing-bad-code

or this one:

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78100/how-do-i-tell-a-senior-programmer-that-i-disagree-with-him

Comment: @tatigo the first has 4 close votes on it right now and will likely get closed.  The second hasn't been seen in over a year and came from an early time in Programmers.SE history (asked 5 years ago, migrated here in 2011) and things have changed since then.

Comment: Thanks MichaelT, I'm not trying to be annoying or anything, just to  better understand how to use the site.

Comment: @tatigo Not annoying at all. With any community, there is history to it and an evolution of thought and policy. Trying to take this all in at once can be quite difficult to understand what was and what is now (and understand those bits of things that you can't quite see).  Please feel free to ask either here (on meta) or in [chat] (the whiteboard). Also note that in the chat room, questions that wouldn't be appropriate (too broad, polling, education advice and the like) can be asked and answered - the different format makes some types of questions easier to answer there than on the main site.

Comment: I ended up deleting my question, since it was put on hold again.